# Displaying multiple classes in one window QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a window that contains a Rectangle and a button on which Loader loads AnotherClass.qml into the Rectangle. This works as expected, but when another button is pressed from AnotherClass.qml, two windows with MainMenu.qml appear.

MainMenu.qml:

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "MainMenu.qml"
    
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: window

        Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                pageLoader.source = "AnotherClass.qml"
            }

        }
        Loader { id: pageLoader; sourceComponent: rect}  
}
}
```

AnotherClass.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

     Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                pageLoader.source = "MainMenu.qml"
            }
        }
        Loader { id: pageLoader; sourceComponent: rect} }
```

I decided to try to implement it in a different way, but the problem remains the same.

```
Rectangle {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MainMenu{
        id: mm
    } 

    Button {
            id: calcButton
            height: 100
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 220

            onClicked: {
                mm.pageLoader.source = "MainMenu.qml"
            }
        } }
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWsyH.gif)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a ton of problems with your code. You probably need to do a little more reading on how to use Loaders. The reason you get two separate Windows is you create a second instance of MainMenu with your Loader. One way to do what you want is something like a StackView.

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "MainMenu.qml"

    StackView {
        id: stack
        initialItem: mainMenu
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: mainMenu

        Rectangle {
            id: rect

            Button {
                id: calcButton
                height: 100
                anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 220

                onClicked: {
                    stack.push(anotherClass)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: anotherClass

        Rectangle {

            Button {
                id: calcButton
                height: 100
                anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 320
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 220

                onClicked: {
                    stack.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```